# Storing time zone as ID string or offset from UTC?

Tags: java, datetime, date, timezone, jodatime

When storing time zone for a given date, is there a particular advantage offered by persisting the time zone's ID string (e.g. Joda's `DateTimeZone.getId()`) versus saving the local time offset from UTC (e.g. Joda's `DateTimeZone.getOffset()`)?

Although Joda's DateTimeZone and the JDK's TimeZone appear to share ID strings, it seems that saving the offset would be more language agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on you're use case.  The offset is language agnostic, but might need to be interpreted back to the ID for a user to pick from.  Most users don't know what they're offset is.
On the other hand, if you're users can be reasonably expected to know their offset, then you don't need to interpret.
It's more of a design decision then it is a best practice issue.

Answer (score 1):

Storing with the offset only you will not know about daylight savings etc. Example from the doc: "Using this system, America/Los_Angeles is expressed as UTC-08:00, or UTC-07:00 in the summer"

Comment: I think I'm missing something.  As I understand it, the offset does account for daylight saving, as in your example: "UTC-08:00, or UTC-07:00 in the summer".  

You wouldn't necessarily be able to determine the actual timezone from the offset, but you could reconstruct local time from UTC.  Is this right?

Comment: Reconstruct local time? Only if you haven't passed one of the two daylight saving dates (if any in that timezone) for that timezone since you saved that offset. And yes you won't be able to determine the actual timezone either.